# Java exec in docker not finding binary

Tags: java, c++, docker, exec

I have a c++ compiled binary (lets called it cbin) that I added to the docker image and want to execute form java.

I tried almost any params for `Runtime.exec` out there:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "cbin"});
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "cbin"});
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cbin");
```

And nothing works!

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

VOLUME ["/root/.config"]

RUN apk --no-cache add bash

ENV PATH="/app:$PATH"

WORKDIR /app
COPY cbin cbin

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e

JAVA_ARGS="-cp jar.jar ClassToRun"

chmod +x cbin

java ${JAVA_ARGS}
```

I tried running:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
```

And I see the file there, but I keep getting `command not found` or `IOException: no such file or directory error=2` etc...

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I am missing here is that you do not copy the jar into the docker image. But I guess that's something missing in the posted code, otherwise you would get an error like:

> Error: Could not find or load main class ClassToRun

I just created a small jar and docker image from your code, and it is working with just the call of:

```
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cbin");
    new Thread(() -> {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).run();
    process.waitFor();
```

I just added the code to get the stderr from the binary and print it out from the java app to see what's going on.

Are you sure that the error messages you see are coming from the Java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cbin")` call? And not from the binary itself?

What if you start the container with:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint bash <your-image-name>
```

and then in the container just run

```
$ cbin
```

Does this work? If you get the same errors here, then it's a problem of `cbin` and not of the Java runtime.

Comment: I acutally managed to fix this by using an ubuntu image and installing java on it, so im guessing it has to do with alpine

Comment: well, the dockerfile you posted worked for me - with alpine; the difference is the binary, so my question, if this was working. It might be that _cbin_ needed some libraries that are not available on alpine but are on ubuntu. Where did you build the cbin binary. Would perhaps be interesting for others to know.

Comment: It need libs thats werent in alpine, but on ubuntu I got an error saying that, while in alpine it said it cant find it, you think it says it cant find it even though it can just because its missing libraries?